# Already php sms function convert to C# success

Tags: c#, sms, sms-gateway

i have already configured SMS gateway & some php code.Now my project is thatone convert it to Csharp with minor changes,

probably i have to write new code.but so.. experienced guys from you i wanted to know is that possible ? Sample code below.

```
enter code here
$username = "abcdsoft";
$password = "softsoft";

//GET parametrar 
//$source     = $_GET['sourceaddr'];
//$dest       = $_GET['destinationaddr'];
//$message_in = $_GET['message'];


enter code here
$source     = $_GET['msisdn'];
$dest       = $_GET['shortcode'];
$message_in = $_GET['msg'];
```

those are most top lines.below code i changed.(php to csharp)

```
enter code here
 string username ='abcdsoft';
 string password = 'abcdabcd';

 int source = ['sourceaddr'];
 int dest  = ['shortcode'];
 string message_in = ['msg'];
```

Is this way is correct ?

Comment: @leppie I'm a beginner ,is this a asp.net or C# ?

Comment: @leppie So..anotherthing.. in here there's no any interface,normally calls to the gateway functions.. then am i write a smsfunc.aspx.cs file or just .class file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost.

1. Need to use double-quotes for the string
2. **Request.QueryString** is the ASP.NET equivalent to the PHP **$_GET**.
3. Also, apparently C# is a bit more strongly typed than PHP, so you need to explicitly convert the query string params to integers.

Code should be like this:

```
string username = "abcdsoft";
string password = "abcdabcd";

int source = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["sourceaddr"]);
int dest  = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["shortcode"]);
string message_in = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["msg"]);
```

Comment: So..anotherthing.. in here there's no any interface,normally calls to the gateway functions.. then am i write a smsfunc.aspx.cs file or just .class file

Comment: @ChathuraRanasinghe I suppose you would put it in the smsfunc.aspx.cs file (code behind).

Comment: string message_in = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["msg"]); is this correct ? String pass like int ?

Comment: @ChathuraRanasinghe I don't think that's right.  int.Parse returns an int.